# how to change x-axis line style in chartjs?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

`zeroLineWidth:0` is not working with it.

my chart options.

```
xAxes: [
    {
        gridLines: {
            display: false
        }
    }
],
yAxes: [
    {
        gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            drawTicks: false,
            borderDash: [4, 4],
            color: "#eee",
            zeroLineWidth: 0
        }
    }
];
```

how to remove or change the x-axis line style?
[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmMH2.png)

Answer (score 1):

`zeroLineWidth` apparently only works if the `yAxis` starts at zero. This can be guaranteed by adding [`ticks.beginAtZero`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#tick-configuration-options) to your `yAxis`.

```
ticks: {
  beginAtZero: true
}
```

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'OK',
      data: [1, 2, 1, 2],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: 'blue'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          drawBorder: false,
          drawTicks: false,
          borderDash: [4, 4],
          color: "#eee",
          zeroLineWidth: 0
        },
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks , the latest version 2.9.3 has fixed this problem